# Ubuntu 15.10 won't run after restarting

Tags: boot, command-line, gnome, screen, 15.10

I downloaded Ubuntu 15.10 and erased the disk and installed it. Afterwards I ran update and upgrade commands and that's it.
I have not updated drivers or anything else. Afterwards I installed GNOME shell and when I restarted my HP laptop it couldn't boot at all.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aphq07

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+alt+f7 and see if it drops you into a command line. log in and run. "sudo apt-get update" then "sudo init 6" and "sudo apt-get upgrade". if that doesn't work it appears that if you re-install ubuntu it is very un-likely that you'll do the exact same thing that caused the error in the first place.

Comment: hi , thanks for fast response.. I managed to open command line and run those commands but still unable to start. I'm downloading 15.04 version now and will post reply if it will be successful

Comment: oops wrong order but I don't think that'll change much: upgrade b4 init 6 well in any case... good luck and hope you can get ubuntu working for you